# Odd error running Behat

Tags: php, symfony1, jenkins, behat

Has anyone gotten the following error running Behat? It seems to me it may be an access rights issue, but the error message is extremely vague.  The file mentioned doesn't exist, which is why I'm guessing access rights.

The thing though is that if the script is run via Jenkins, then the temp file is `C:/Windows/Temp/sf2DA1B.tmp` and I can't imagine both being an access rights issue.

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource(): Invalid Schema in phar://C:/Program Files (x86)/Behat/behat.phar/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 363

  [InvalidArgumentException]

  [ERROR 4] Document is empty (in file:///C:/Users/vaillancourt/AppData/Local/Temp/2/sf2D71B.tmp - line 1, column 1)

  [ERROR 4] Start tag expected, '<' not found (in file:///C:/Users/vaillancourt/AppData/Local/Temp/2/sf2D71B.tmp - line 1, column 1)

  [ERROR 3067] Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to parse the XML resource 'file:///C:/Users/vaillancourt/AppData/Local/Temp/2/sf2D71B.tmp'. (in in_memory_buffer - line 8, col
umn 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to try to manually download "services-1.0.xsd" from here- 
http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd

Place the file into $PATH_TO_SYMFONY2/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/ schema/dic/services. If you’re lucky enough, it will work – which was the case on one of my test setups.

Comment: i suppose it should.. did you try it out ?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to work. But decided to get the source from GIT and install it that way.  That seems to have resolved it.

Comment: strange.. it worked for me but.. anyways the problem's solved so everyone's happy :)